# Using zero constant as long in a less verbose way

Tags: scala, types, long-integer

Currently I am creating a function to sum Long numbers in a functional way. My first attempt was this.

```
def aVeryBigSum(ar: Array[Long]): Long = (0 /: ar) (_ + _)
```

Leading to an error due to ambiguous conversion.

`error: type mismatch;
 found   : x$2.type (with underlying type Int)
 required: ?{def +(x$1: ? >: Long): ?}
 Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method int2long in object Int of type (x: Int)Long
 and method int2float in object Int of type (x: Int)Float
 are possible conversion functions from x$2.type to ?{def +(x$1: ? >: Long): ?}
       def aVeryBigSum(ar: Array[Long]): Long = (0 /: ar) (_ + _)
                                                           ^`

My working next attempt was an explicit conversion with a rather verbose result but currently working.

`def aVeryBigSum(ar: Array[Long]): Long =
    (0.asInstanceOf[Long] /: ar) (_ + _)`

I am starting with Scala so I think that I could be misunderstanding the error.

Is there any more proper solution?

Comment: `def aVeryBigSum(ar: Array[Long]): Long = (0L /: ar) (_ + _)` works just fine.

Comment: replace 0 with `0L` i.e `(0L /: ar) (_ + _)`

Comment: This is already a built-in function sum that you can use:  val ar: Array[Long] = Array(1, 2, 3); println(ar.sum)